# Different version of bash running on git pre-commits on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, git, zsh, yarnpkg, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 along with some Git 2.17.1 pre-commits. I've install *zsh* as my default shell using *chsh*. Anytime that a commit happens, a set of *yarn* commands runs to lint and unit test Javascript code. The *yarn* script in *package.json* that does the lint check is:

```
read -r CHANGES <<< `git diff-index --name-only HEAD | grep 'workspaces/.*/\\(src\\|test\\)/.\\+\\.jsx\\?$' | tr '\\n' ' '`; if [[ $CHANGES ]]; then yarn eslint ${CHANGES}; fi;
```

When yarn tries to run this, I receive a `Syntax error: redirection unexpected` error. If I take that same command and run it straight from the *zsh* prompt, it works fine.

The pre-commit hook file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./node_modules/pre-commit/hook
RESULT=$?
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

and the hook file in node_modules looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

HAS_NODE=`which node 2> /dev/null || which nodejs 2> /dev/null || which iojs 2> /dev/null`

#
# There are some issues with Source Tree because paths are not set correctly for
# the given environment. Sourcing the bash_profile seems to resolve this for bash users,
# sourcing the zshrc for zshell users.
#
# https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/140339/sourcetree-hook-failing-because-paths-don-t-seem-to-be-set-correctly
#
function source_home_file {
  file="$HOME/$1"
  [[ -f "${file}" ]] && source "${file}"
}

if [[ -z "$HAS_NODE" ]]; then
  source_home_file ".bash_profile" || source_home_file ".zshrc" || source_home_file ".bashrc" || true
fi

NODE=`which node 2> /dev/null`
NODEJS=`which nodejs 2> /dev/null`
IOJS=`which iojs 2> /dev/null`
LOCAL="/usr/local/bin/node"
BINARY=

#
# Figure out which binary we need to use for our script execution.
#
if [[ -n "$NODE" ]]; then
  BINARY="$NODE"
elif [[ -n "$NODEJS" ]]; then
  BINARY="$NODEJS"
elif [[ -n "$IOJS" ]]; then
  BINARY="$IOJS"
elif [[ -x "$LOCAL" ]]; then
  BINARY="$LOCAL"
fi

#
# Add --dry-run cli flag support so we can execute this hook without side affects
# and see if it works in the current environment
#
if [[ $* == *--dry-run* ]]; then
  if [[ -z "$BINARY" ]]; then
    exit 1
  fi
else
  "$BINARY" "$("$BINARY" -e "console.log(require.resolve('pre-commit'))")"
fi
```

There are other users using OSX that run these hooks as well and it works find for them. Is there some way I can get this to work on Ubuntu? Is *yarn* or *git* running some other version of *bash/dash* that produces the redirection error, and if so, can I change that?

Comment: You say you tested your command interactively in zsh, but have you tested it in bash, which is what your scripts run in, according to their she-bang line: `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the answer by bk2204, I did some more digging around about how to change the shell that is invoked by any process. I found a [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064774) about changing the Ubuntu shell. Once I did that the pre-commits correctly work.

Comment: While that may work on your system, be aware that if anyone else is working on this project, they'll run into the same issue. It isn't safe to assume any behavior from `/bin/sh` on Debian or Ubuntu that isn't [POSIX plus a few extensions](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files#scripts).

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the yarn script you're using is actually being run by `/bin/sh`, which on Ubuntu is `dash`, not `bash` or `zsh`. Most programs which invoke a shell will invoke only `/bin/sh`, ignoring your personal shell. That's important because a user may have a shell such as `tcsh` which is not POSIX-compatible, and the scripts would fail otherwise.

In `dash`, here-strings (the `<<<` syntax) are not available, so you'll probably need to switch that syntax to use an echo instead. Note also that the double-brackets notation is a bashism and is similarly unlikely to work, so you should replace it with single brackets and quotes around the variable.